# How do i redirect output to the Pester xml file?

Tags: powershell, appveyor, pester

I would like to know how to add additional output to the Pester test XML file using PowerShell commands such as `Out-Host` or `Write-Debug`.

I wish to do this so that I can observe the output on the appveyor tests page. [image: example appveyor tests page]

As you can see in the above image the pester tests do not have an Std OUT option.

In searching for an answer I stumbled upon this [github issue](https://github.com/pester/Pester/issues/301) which described the exact thing I want to do but doesn't provide a solution.

The only workaround I have been able to get to work is to force the pester test to write to the console using `Out-Host` so that I can cross reference the output with the test.

Comment: I wonder if you could run [Add-AppveyorTest](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/build-worker-api/#add-tests) as [AfterEach](https://github.com/pester/Pester/wiki/BeforeEach-and-AfterEach) command instead of uploading XML results. But I cannot find how to access current test data from `AfterEach` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think per the issue you linked to, this is currently not possible and will only become possible when the developers of Pester build it in as functionality. I suggest raising a new issue for it on GitHub as the one you referenced was quite old. It seems like a pretty valid request.

It's worth noting also that Pester already captures the error output of failed tests into the nunit xml output.

Comment: if I can learn enough about how Pester works I might see if I can expose a verb like "Write-MessageField" which will allow for piping content to the nunit xml message field.